# When use function 'plot' to plot a function in r, what do the output t and y mean, and what arguments are available?

Tags: r

I have a toy sample of only four numbers and I want to plot the empirical distribution function and the quantile function (the inverse of edf). The code looks like this:

```
x <- c(-1.55, -0.67, -0.39,  0.60)    
test = sort(x)     

#Empirical cdf 
plotout = plot(stepfun(sort(test), (0:4)/4), main="Empirical cdf")     
segments(plotout$t[1], 0.4, plotout$t[3], 0.4, col="red")    
segments(plotout$t[3], -0.04, plotout$t[3], 0.4, col="red")

#Empirical quantile function 
plotout = plot(stepfun((1:3)/4, sort(test)), main="Empirical quantile function") 
segments(0.4, 1.04*plotout$y[1], 0.4, plotout$y[2], col="red")    
segments(-0.04, plotout$y[2], 0.4, plotout$y[2], col="red")
```

I realized that the arguments for plotting this 'stepfun', a function, were quite different from plotting (x,y) data points, for example, you can't use `type='l'` here. So what arguments are available then? To be specific, for the quantile function, there were only 3 points got dotted, as shown in the result figure

[image]

How can I dot the first missed point?
And what are the above 'plotout$t', 'plotout$y' in the code?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Just pointing a piece of information from the help, `?stepfun`: `y:  
numeric vector one longer than x, giving the heights of the function values between the x values.`

Comment: I am afraid this is not the answer to my question... What are the output t's and y's from function plot? And what are the proper arguments for plot(function,...) instead of our familiar plot(x,y,...)? Thank you.